# Don't display both the Q&A of self-answers in the Top Network/Meta posts on the Profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The Top Network part of my profile page looks kinda ridiculous it's just MSE FAQs.

[image: Frogs with unicorn horns]

Where someone has posted both the question and the answer to a question and they appear in the Top Network Posts can the answer be removed? I assume that the same issue will appear in the Top Meta Posts.

To a certain extent I'm my own worst enemy as I've only really been active on MSE and SO but I do have *some* other posts out there that might better to display.

Comment: [I have 2 duplicates in mine too…](http://i.imgur.com/0NuBH3w.png) It's so annoying! I have plenty of other posts I'd like to show off there. (I think it would be right to show only the higher score copy.) I demand equality for self-answerers!